# Cannot access matlab function output - variable undefined

Tags: matlab, function, plot, undefined

I'm trying to plot a curve using the equation `curve = (1/(sqrt(2*pi*s.^2))* exp(-((tempAnomaly-m).^2)/(2*s.^2)));`. I have my program split into two functions, but when calling the calculating function from the main function, I can't seem to access the 'curve' variable even though it is the output value. I am getting the error "Undefined function or variable" on line 4 (`plot(tempAnomaly, curve);`).

Any tips on how to access this variable so I'm able to plot it would be great. Thanks!

```
function TempAnomaly()
tempAnomaly = linspace(-5, 5, 1000);
normalDist(0.4, 0.1, tempAnomaly)
plot(tempAnomaly, curve);
end

function curve = normalDist(m, s, tempAnomaly)
curve = (1/(sqrt(2*pi*s.^2))* exp(-((tempAnomaly-m).^2)/(2*s.^2)));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of `normalDist` should be equal to `curve` in line 4. So `curve` is undefined in line 4

```
function TempAnomaly()
    tempAnomaly = linspace(-5, 5, 1000);
    curve = normalDist(0.4, 0.1, tempAnomaly) %%% <- correct this line
    plot(tempAnomaly, curve);
end
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. How do I plot the graph differently so that curve isn't undefined..?

Comment: Copy my code instead of TempAnomaly you provided. I added `curve =` to your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it